# How to show $\displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^n \cos\left((k+l)\frac{\pi (j-1/2)}{n}\right) = 0$

Tags: summation, trigonometric-series, exponential-sum

This result seems trivial, how would I show $$\sum_{j=1}^n \cos\left((k+l)\frac{\pi (j-1/2)}{n}\right) = 0$$
Where $0 \le k,l \le n-1$
And $k \neq l \neq 0$.

I tried to use the exponential definition and geo sum formula but I didn't get any trivial simplifications. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think your formula is true. If you take $k=2$ and $n=1$ your sum equals $\cos(\pi)=-1 \neq 0$ if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @jasnee Sorry let me update the question.

Comment: $k+l$ should be even. Otherwise, the identity does not hold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\begin{equation} \begin{split}
&\displaystyle \sum_{j=1}^N \cos \left( \dfrac{k \pi}{N} \left({j-\frac{1}{2} }\right) \right) \\
&= \displaystyle \cos \left(\dfrac{k \pi}{2N} \right)\sum_{j=1}^N \cos\left( \dfrac{ jk \pi}{N} \right)
+ \sin \left(\dfrac{k \pi}{2N}\right)  \sum_{j=1}^N \sin\left( \dfrac{ j k\pi}{N}\right)  \end{split}\end{equation}$

Now we have,

$\begin{equation} \begin{split}
\displaystyle & \sum_{j=1}^N \cos \left(\dfrac{j k \pi}{N} \right)\\ 
&= \displaystyle Re \left(\sum_{j=1}^N \exp \left( \dfrac{j ik \pi}{N} \right) \right) \\
&= \exp \left( \dfrac{i k \pi}{N} \right) \cdot \dfrac{ \exp\left( i k \pi \right) - 1 }{ \exp \left(\dfrac{i k \pi}{N} \right) - 1 } = 0 \\  
\end{split} \end{equation} $

and similarly for the $\sin$ term.

Comment: If $k=1$, then $\exp(ik\pi)=-1$, so the identity does not hold.

Comment: You're right.  This also true for any odd $k$.  May be there is something wrong in the question.

Answer (score 0):

The identity holds only for even $k+l$. Suppose $k+l$ is even. Using
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}=\frac{1-x^n}{1-x}$$
one has
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\sum_{j=1}^n \cos\left((k+l)\frac{\pi (j-1/2)}{n}\right) \\
&=&\Re\sum_{j=1}^n e^{(k+l)\frac{\pi (j-1/2)}{n}i} \\
&=&\Re \bigg[e^{-(k+l)\frac{\pi}{2n}i}\sum_{j=1}^n e^{(k+l)\frac{\pi j}{n}i} \bigg]\\
&=&\Re \bigg[e^{-(k+l)\frac{\pi}{2n}i}\sum_{j=1}^n \bigg(e^{(k+l)\frac{\pi}{n}i} \bigg)^j\bigg]\\
&=&\Re\bigg[e^{-(k+l)\frac{\pi}{2n}i}e^{(k+l)\frac{\pi}{n}i}\frac{1-(e^{(k+l)\frac{\pi}{n}i})^n}{1-e^{(k+l)\frac{\pi}{n}i}}\bigg]\\
&=&0.
\end{eqnarray}